# $ 2.28319 = 0 $ !? - How do I spot the mistake?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I am given $ f(t) = e^{\sin(t)} $ and $ F(x) = \int\limits_{0}^{x} f(t) dt $ and have to compute: $\int\limits_{-0.5  \pi}^{0.5 \pi} \sin(x) F(\cos(x)) dx  $

How do I go about this problem?

Thus far I got: $ I :=\int\limits_{-0.5  \pi}^{0.5 \pi} \sin(x) F(\cos(x)) dx = -\int\limits_{-1}^{1} F(u) du $ $ \ \ \ $(*)

And: $$ \int\limits_{-0.5  \pi}^{0.5 \pi} \sin(x) F(\cos(x)) = -cos(x) F(cos(x)) - \int\limits_{-0.5  \pi}^{0.5 \pi} \sin(x) F'(\cos(x)) \cos(x) dx = 0 + \int\limits_{-1}^{1} F'(u)u du = [F(u)u]_{-1}^{1} - \int\limits_{-1}^{1} F(u)du = 2.28319 + I  $$

Remembering (*) I get: $$  2.28319 = 0$$, which cannot be.

I am have run my calculations down from top to bottom and up again and seem not able to find the mistake. I would be very happy, if someone could point it point it out in the comments.

Comment: Are you sure the top isn't supposed to be $0.5\pi$? Right now, it's $0.5x$, which makes no sense.

Comment: Please don't ask people to answer in the comments. That already happens more than enough, and it results in questions remaining unanswered. The standard way to answer a question is to post an answer so that the answer can be accepted and the question no longer appears on the list of unanswered questions.

Comment: You need to pay more attention to your limits. In $(*)$ the limits are different for $u$ from those for $x$. Note also the comment above by @NobleMushtak

Answer (score 1):

After the integration by parts, your new integral should be:
$$-\cos xF(\cos x)-\int \sin(x)F'(\cos x)\cos x \ dx=-\cos xF(\cos x)-\int \sin(x)e^{\sin (\cos x)}\cos x \ dx$$

Comment: ye, I added the ' mark.

Comment: @blauerschluessel And then you lose it again when you do the u-substitution.

Answer (score 1):

Substituting $u=\cos x, du=-\sin x dx$ gives $\;\displaystyle\int\limits_{-0.5  \pi}^{0.5 \pi} \sin(x) F(\cos(x)) dx=-\int_0^0 F(u)du=0$