# How to solve: $\int\limits_{-\pi \cdot 0.5}^{\pi \cdot 0.5} \sin(x) \int\limits_{0}^{\cos(x)} e^{\sin(t)} \, dt \, dx$

Tags: integration

Let $ f(t) = e^{\sin(t)} $ and $ F(x) = \int\limits_0^x f(t) \, dt $ and then one has to find: $\int\limits_{-0.5  \pi}^{0.5 \pi} \sin(x) F(\cos(x)) \, dx  $

Thus far I got: $$ I :=\int_{-0.5  \pi}^{0.5 \pi} \sin(x) F(\cos(x)) \, dx = -\int\limits_{-1}^{1} F(u) \, du \tag{$*$} $$

And:

\begin{align}
& \int_{-0.5  \pi}^{0.5 \pi} \sin(x) F(\cos(x)) \,dx \\[10pt]
= {} & -\cos(x) F(\cos(x)) - \int_{-0.5  \pi}^{0.5 \pi} \sin(x) F'(\cos(x)) \cos(x) \, dx = 0 + \int_{-1}^1 F'(u)u \, du \\[10pt]
= {} & \left[F(u)u \vphantom{\frac 1 1} \right]_{-1}^1 - \int_{-1}^1 F(u) \, du
\end{align}

Remebering $(*)$, it is indicated that: $\left[ F(u)u \vphantom{\frac \int \int} \right]_{-1}^1 = 0 $, however this does not seem right. Does anyone have an idea, how to approach this problem best?

Comment: I think Fubini's Theorem will help.

Comment: Why not write the limits as $-\pi/2,\pi/2?$

Comment: You've asked the same question [twice](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1831006/frac-pi2e-frace-pi2-0-how-do-i-spot-the-mistake#1831006). Edit your original post if you need to make changes.

Comment: Notice that $\cos(\frac{\pi}{2})=0$